# ListView clear() prevents new contents showing

Tags: .net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.1

The following code works fine in framework 4.7.2

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.View = View.List;
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        listView1.Items.Add("A");
        listView1.Items.Add("B");
        listView1.Items.Add("C");
    }
}
```

However in .Net Core 3 the presense of the .clear() causes the other items not to display.

[Update]
I should include the following

```
   private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem listViewItem4 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem("");
            this.listView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView();
            this.Column1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader();
            this.richTextBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
            this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            // 
            // listView1
            // 
            this.listView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader[] {
            this.Column1});
            this.listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
            this.listView1.GridLines = true;
            this.listView1.HideSelection = false;
            this.listView1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem[] {
            listViewItem4});
            this.listView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 7);
            this.listView1.Name = "listView1";
            this.listView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(849, 316);
            this.listView1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.listView1.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
            this.listView1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.listView1_SelectedIndexChanged);
            // 
            // Column1
            // 
            this.Column1.Name = "Column1";
            this.Column1.Text = "Name";
            this.Column1.Width = 500;
            // 
            // richTextBox1
            // 
            this.richTextBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 329);
            this.richTextBox1.Name = "richTextBox1";
            this.richTextBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(850, 265);
            this.richTextBox1.TabIndex = 3;
            this.richTextBox1.Text = "";
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 610);
            this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
            this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(753, 23);
            this.textBox1.TabIndex = 4;
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(778, 609);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(74, 22);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 5;
            this.button1.Text = "button1";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(7F, 15F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(865, 661);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.richTextBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.listView1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);

        }

       private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
        // does nothing 
        }
```

Comment: No, that works just fine when I try it.  No real idea what InitializeComponent() did to initialize the ListView.  If you run Win7 then watch out for an exception that doesn't stop the program nor debugger.

Comment: I want to delete this question but can not because it has an open bounty. The problem was that I should have set listview1.View = View.Details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had

```
 listview1.View = View.Details
```

It needs to be

```
 listview1.View = View.List
```

Comment: I would prefer to delete the question but I can't because it has the bonus applied.

Answer (score -1):

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.View = View.List;  <---- instead of this : listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        listView1.Items.Add("A");
        listView1.Items.Add("B");
        listView1.Items.Add("C");
    }
```

[image: microsoft docs example]

From the official documentation of ListView.View Property : [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.view?view=netframework-4.8)

Propably it was a fast typo from your end. 
Let me know.